excel sheet all photo download with serial_number, name, and Photo column
I have an Excel sheet with serial_number, name, and photo column. I need to download all photos row by row by follow this file name convention:- "[serial_number][name].jpg”.
My Excel sheet: https://filebin.net/qi9k9nqf53txgpfb
This code not working...
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
import io
import numpy as np  # Import numpy for NaN checking

# Read the Excel file
df = pd.read_excel('Batch-1.xlsx')

# Iterate through rows
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    serial_number = row['sl']
    name = row['name']
    photo_data = row['photo']

    # Check if photo_data is NaN (float in pandas)
    if isinstance(photo_data, float) and np.isnan(photo_data):
        print(f"No photo data found for row {index + 1}. Skipping...")
        continue

    # Convert bytes data to image
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(photo_data))

    # Save the image with the specified file name convention
    file_name = f"{serial_number} {name}.jpg"
    image.save(file_name)

    print(f"Photo saved: {file_name}")


output:
I see all images there but why code says:
"No photo data found for row 1. Skipping...
No photo data found for row 2. Skipping...
No photo data found for row 3. Skipping...
No photo data found for row 4. Skipping...
No photo data found for row 5. Skipping...
No photo data found for row 6. Skipping...
No photo data found for row 7. Skipping...
No photo data found for row 8. Skipping...
No photo data found for row 9. Skipping...
No photo data found for row 10. Skipping...
No photo data found for row 11. Skipping...
No photo data found for row 12. Skipping...
No photo data found for row 13. Skipping...
No photo data found for row 14. Skipping...
No photo data found for row 15. Skipping...
No photo data found for row 16. Skipping...
No photo data found for row 17. Skipping...
No photo data found for row 18. Skipping...
No photo data found for row 19. Skipping...
No photo data found for row 20. Skipping...
No photo data found for row 21. Skipping...
No photo data found for row 22. Skipping...
No photo data found for row 23. Skipping...
No photo data found for row 24. Skipping...
No photo data found for row 25. Skipping...
No photo data found for row 26. Skipping...
No photo data found for row 27. Skipping...
No photo data found for row 28. Skipping...
No photo data found for row 29. Skipping...
No photo data found for row 30. Skipping...


Pandas is more for manipulating data not images. If you want to save images from an Excel Sheet Openpyxl is probably better. See example here

I need to dowload images with naming convaction, I have huge excel data images need to download by "sl no. and name.jpg" like this file name format. How I do that. It saves my life.

Hello @moken, can you please give me the actual code for my task to complete, download all images by file name convacation. I reallly appreciate you.
my excel sheet: https://filebin.net/qi9k9nqf53txgpfb

The following code sample adapted from the suggested link will extract the images and save as jpeg files to a subdirectory called 'images'.
The files are named from the 'serial number' from Column A and 'name' from Column B.
Code Sample
import os.path
from io import BytesIO
import string
import openpyxl
from PIL import Image

# Load workbook
xl_images = 'Batch_1.xlsx'
xl_sheet = 'Batch 1'

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(xl_images)
ws = wb[xl_sheet]

# Set path for saved images
images_path = 'Images'

# ### Loop to find and save images
for image in ws._images:
    # Get row and column info where the image is located
    row = image.anchor._from.row + 1
    col = image.anchor._from.col

    # Image name in opposite cell to the TL of image
    image_name = ws.cell(row=row, column=col).value

    print(f"Image '{image_name}' located at: {f'{string.ascii_uppercase[col]}{row}'}")

    # Get image bytes
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(image._data()))

    ### Image name from Cell values 'Serial Number' and 'Name'
    img_name = f"{ws[f'A{row}'].value}_{image_name}"

    img_save_path = os.path.join(images_path, f"{img_name}.jpg")

    ### Save image
    img.save(img_save_path)


Images created in the 'Images' folder.


Why not just extract the files from the zip archive?

@Charlie Clark because the 'serial number' and 'name' are in the Sheet

Sure, but if you look at the archive source, you'll see the images. Read the sheet in read-only mode and extract the files directly from the archive. Apart from that, it looks like you've forgotten the cell.offset() method and I'm not sure when you go numeric to alphabetical to numeric for the column index.
